# Dependency Issue with Gemfiles and Webrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, webrick

I've been trying to configure webrick to use SSL on all pages of my application.

I added

```
gem 'rack-ssl', :require => 'rack/ssl'
```

to my gem file and

```
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, "Rack::SSL"
config.force_ssl = true
```

to my /config/application.rb file. And I configured webrick to use my self signed certificate by modifying my /script/rails file to looke like so

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rails/commands/server'
require 'rack'
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'

module Rails
  class Server < ::Rack::Server
    def default_options
      super.merge({
          :Port => 3001,
          :environment => (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "development").dup,
          :daemonize => false,
          :debugger => false,
          #:pid => File.expand_path("tmp/pids/server.pid"),
          :config => File.expand_path("config.ru"),
          :SSLEnable => true,
          :SSLVerifyClient => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER,
          :SSLPrivateKey => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new( File.open("home/sureweb/rubystuff/server.cert.key").read),
      :SSLCertificate => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open("home/sureweb/rubystuff/server.cert.crt").read),
          :SSLCACertificateFile => 'home/sureweb/rubystuff/server.crt',
          :SSLCertName => [["CN", WEBrick::Utils::getservername]]
     })
    end
  end
end

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'rails/commands'
```

But every time I run rails s I get a message saying

```
You have already activated activesupport 3.2.3, but your Gemfile requires activesupport 3.0.12. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

Normally I could solve this by removing the version 3.2.3 but I have numerous other gems that depend on it so that is not an option. Is there another way to get this working?